# How do I replace string with 0 in multiple columns in Pyspark

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

As in the title. I have a list of columns and need to replace a certain string with 0 in these columns. I can do that using select statement with nested when function but I want to preserve my original dataframe and only change the columns in question. df.replace(string, 0, list_of_columns) doesn't work as there is a data type mismatch.

Comment: a column in pyspark can have only 1 data type. so, you can replace a string with string -- try `"0"`

Answer (score 0):

So I ended up with something like this which worked for me:

```
for column in column_list:
    df = df.withColumn(column, F.when((F.col(column) == "string"), "0").otherwise(F.col(column)))
```